# Fancybox error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fancybox

I have been made a post model with picture upload and attached fancybox to display these pictures and this all works great.

Example:

```
<div id="pictures_in_form"><%= link_to image_tag(asset.object.image.url(:thumb)), asset.object.image.url(:big), :class => "fancybox", :rel => "gallery" if asset.object.image? %></div>
```

But when I want to attach a fancybox to a single image, I have error:

```
The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.
```

Example:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag 'about_school/par_livu_skolu_1.jpg'), '/about_school/par_livu_skolu_1.jpg', :class => "fancybox"%>
```

So can anyone point to the problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your opening parens like this:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag ('about_school/par_livu_skolu_1.jpg'), '/about_school/par_livu_skolu_1.jpg', :class => "fancybox") %>
```

That might fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The first image path starts **without** slash `/` like :

```
about_school/par_livu_skolu_1.jpg
```

... so it indicates a *relative* path. If the calling page, for instance, is located in a subdirectory like :

```
/mysubdir/page.html
```

... then the image path will be

```
/mysubdir/about_school/par_livu_skolu_1.jpg
```

On the other hand, the second image path **does** start with slash `/` like :

```
/about_school/par_livu_skolu_1.jpg
```

...which means that the image path starts from `root` regardless where the calling page is located.

I guess you need to correct either path, whatever is correct otherwise fancybox won't find the image and will display the message

```
The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.
```