# fancy box image popup

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I want to show image on click on it. I am using Paperclip to store images, and Fancy-box installed to process image display.
But I get such error.

```
The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.
```

I searched in SO, and found similair question, [Fancybox error in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011694/fancybox-error-in-rails)
tried to change links like suggested but no results.

My application.js file looks like this.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree 
//= require fancybox

$(document).ready(function() { $("a.fancybox").fancybox(); });
```

My show view where I want to see the popup of the image (like in this example http://fancybox.net/ ), looks like this.

```
<a class="fancybox"><%= image_tag @product.photo.url(:thumb) %></a>
```

Comment: You should include `<%= @product.photo.url %>` on target link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proper example of fancybox with source code: https://www.mgtechnologies.co.in/product/fancybox-responsive-jquery-pop-up

try this:

```
    <a class="fancybox" href="<%= @product.photo.url(:full) %>">
         <%= image_tag @product.photo.url(:thumb) %>
    </a>
```

next

```
    $("a.fancybox") - is overhead selector
    $(".fancybox") - enought
```

after clicking the fancybox link check Network tab in devTools, it could be server error
http://monosnap.com/image/tByHYsWqawv0k5NAVvJrFgpt8

you could find some samples and check api in modern documentation of fancybox here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Try that work around for understand what is going on:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.fancybox', (e)->
        $.fancybox.showLoading()
        $.ajax
               url: $(this).attr('href')
               success: (data)->
                 $.fancybox.hideLoading()
                 $.fancybox(data, {
                  afterShow:()->
                     // TODO something
                  overlay :
                    locked : true

                 })

                 true

               dataType: 'html'

        e.preventDefault()
      )
```

Comment: Thanks, now when I click on the image it shows in new window with `http://localhost:3000/system/products/photos/000/000/039/original/CitySkid9V3_9V4.jpg` link. but why image is not poping up? Because that is what I whant to achieve, does I have to add some functionality in application.js file to do that. I thought that Fancy Box is doing all alone :(

Comment: 1. U have got bad //= require fancybox path
2. server return image with bad header. Try to user options for ajax request 
'ajax:
{
 dataType : 'html',
 headers  : { 'X-fancyBox': true }
}'
3. server return html content with js that broke your page

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try with

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require fancybox
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

jQuery(function() {
  $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

application.css

```
*= require_self
*= require fancybox
*= require_tree .
```

your view page

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(@product.photo.url(:thumb)), @product.photo.url(:full), :class => 'fancybox')%>
```

Comment: Yea, now I have image rendered on page but it don't pop up like in example. It just shows up on bottom of the page

Comment: Strange! Question: is there any javascript error been shown in the firebug console?

Comment: Its a wild guess: Please check have you added the css for fancybox or not?

Comment: I downloaded files from [HERE](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) putted in project folder and now I have working image popup [Like this](http://gyazo.com/cf5f7a985517cb95fe068f38a994e21e), but it's too bad, because I don't have any option except Escape button to quit this image.

Comment: @Egards, you can use the gem for this. Please check https://github.com/hecticjeff/fancybox-rails. If you have downloaded the fancybox, please check in your page, the stylesheet for the fancybox is getting loaded or not. If it is not there, then you need to add <link rel="stylesheet" href="your-path-to-jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> in the html part.

Comment: I already installed that gem, I done everything what I was told but that didn't work so I downloaded theese files so no It's almost working